# open few webpages of site with https and rest of the site with http

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have site like www.example.com, we have few web pages that should open with https through .htaccess and rest of the site should open with http .

following page should be open on https

`1.  www.example.com/site/orders/checkout`

`2.  www.example.com/myaccountarea/checkoutlogin`

I did the following code in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
#this page has to be on https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/orders/checkout$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https//www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#this page has to be on https
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/myaccountarea/checkoutlogin$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https//www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

#all other pages have to be on http
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$  [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/orders/checkout$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myaccountarea/checkoutlogin$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http//www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

When I tried to open `"https//www.example.com/myaccountarea/checkoutlogin"` it redirected me to `"http//www.example.com/index.php"`.

Please suggest how I can get the desire result.

complete .htaccess

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(orders/checkout|myaccount/checkoutlogin|orders/getshippingadds/shippingId|orders/getbillingadds/billingId|search/userstats)[\s/?] [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ https//%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

these page has to be on http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(orders/checkout|myaccount/checkoutlogin|orders/getshippingadds/shippingId|orders/getbillingadds/billingId|search/userstats)[\s/?] [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ http//%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]


 Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http//www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|html|htm|xml|txt|xsl)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536050"
</FilesMatch>


# BEGINNING of DEFLATE instructions
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css application/javascript
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Connection keep-alive
</IfModule>
```

Thanks
Simarjeet

Comment: You probably don't really want to do this. Starting when you assign the user a session cookie associated with any sensitive process (like an ecommerce checkout), all future requests should be via HTTPS. It's not enough just to protect the forms in question; the session cookie is also sensitive information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `THE_REQUEST` variable:

```
RewriteEngine on

#these page has to be on https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(orders/checkout|myaccountarea/checkoutlogin)[\s/?] [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

#these page has to be on http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(orders/checkout|myaccountarea/checkoutlogin)[\s/?] [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

**PS:** I have also merged your first 2 rules into one using regex alternation.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, It slow my site also I am getting session lost from during the http to https redirection ..it was working before ..

Comment: I have pasted complete .htaccess, I have add few more page , which I require to be on https.

Comment: Comment out your `www` adding rule and clear your browser cache. Then retest.

Comment: but I want my site open with www

Comment: Then move that rule as first rule just below `RewriteEngine` line.